# Dynamics CRM Chart Custom Order and Filter

Tags: xml, charts, dynamics-crm

I have a Microsoft Dynamics CRM Chart which I'm trying to edit so that it only shows specific grouped data in a specific order that I'm defining.

I've exported the XML and edited it so that I have the following data snippet:

```
<datadescription>
  <datadefinition>
    <fetchcollection>
      <fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true">
        <entity name="opportunity">
          <attribute name="estimatedvalue" aggregate="sum" alias="sum_estimatedvalue" />
          <attribute name="stepname" groupby="true" alias="stepname" />
        </entity>
      </fetch>
    </fetchcollection>
    <categorycollection>
      <category alias="stepname">
        <measurecollection>
          <measure alias="sum_estimatedvalue">
        </measurecollection>
      </category>
    </categorycollection>
  </datadefinition>
</datadescription>
```

Basically the data is currently grouped by `stepname` (there are 15 steps) and each step name contains the `sum` of each `estimatedvalue`.

Now what I want to do is only show 5 of the step names (basically filter out the rest) and keep them in this order below:

> 2-Proposal Created
>
> 4-Fees
>
> 6-Open Plan
>
> 12-Advisor Invoice
>
> 13-Financial Finesse invoice

How can I edit the chart XML to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the chart XML you can see there is a FetchXML statement. You can edit this to filter and order as required:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" aggregate="true" >
  <entity name="opportunity" >
    <attribute name="estimatedvalue" aggregate="sum" alias="sum_estimatedvalue" />
    <attribute name="stepname" groupby="true" alias="stepname" />
    <order alias="stepname" />
    <filter type="and" >
      <condition attribute="stepname" operator="in" >
        <value>2-Proposal Created</value>
        <value>4-Fees</value>
        <value>6-Open Plan</value>
        <value>12-Advisor Invoice</value>
        <value>13-Financial Finesse invoice</value>
      </condition>
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

I tested the FetchXML in a fetch builder/executor and it does works through that. I have never edited the chart xml quite like this though, but in theory the above should work.